# Inter-symbol energy coding

Tags: channelcoding

I have scoured my entire library and I can't find where I read about a method of using symbol energy intentionally smeared across multiple bit times in such a way that the symbols can be recovered correctly. Can someone point to any of the classic digital modulation books I am likely to have in my library where I would have read about this technique? I seem to recall it was a part of minimum shift keying techniques. It is frustrating that I can remember one or two of the figures but can't place where I read it.

Thanks.

Ray

Comment: Are you thinking of partial response signaling? It's related to continuous phase modulation. There's a chapter about it in Proakis.

Comment: I think it is too, still qualifies for an answer even though it is short @MBaz and it would also "close" the question gracefully.

Comment: @A_A It's done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely possibility is that you're thinking of [partial response signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_phase_modulation#Partial_response_CPM), of which GMSK is a special case. This is covered in many textbooks, e.g. in Proakis.

Comment: Thanks y'all. That is sufficient information to continue my search. That is exactly what I was thinking of. How do I mark this question as answered? MBaz, thanks for the link.

Comment: @RMack I'm glad I could help. You should be able to click on the up arrow and the check mark on the answer's left-hand side.